# how to create CountDownTimer that execute command every 10 mins

Tags: java, android

I want to make an Android app that starts counting down from 10 mins and when it reaches 0, it should execute a command to send data via internet.
After that it should start all over again from 10 mins. It should keep sending data every 10 mins until I manually stop it.

(I have already created command to send data via internet and it works perfectly, but I don't know how to make the count down timer.)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Alarmmanager will help you with your task

Comment: @Yahor10 why don't you put this as an answer ... others answer are so wrong!

Answer (score 2):

```
public class MyCounter extends CountDownTimer
{

    public MyCounter(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) 
    {
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() 
    {
        System.out.println("Timer Completed.");  
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
        {
          //Your function here..
        }
}
```

Before `oncreate`,

```
final MyCounter timer = new MyCounter(Long.MAX_VALUE,600000);
```

In `oncreate`,

```
timer.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the concept of multi threading in java, make a thread and make it sleep for minutes as it wakes call the code/method in, you can start thread

```
class SampleThread extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(600000);
            callYourmethodHere();
        } 
                     catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        } 

    }

SampleThread t = new SampleThread();
    t.start();
```

start the timer when ever required